# How to show an error in the front-end if there's unprocessable content in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I was working on a register page for an application. And everything works fine, except for this one small bit.

Whenever something doesn't match these requirements that I have in a custom http request it just throws an 422 error.

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'middle_name' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:user|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/',
        ];
    }
```

My question is, how can I send it the error to my front-end, so I can display it for the user?

Some additional info that may be important:

- using Laravel 9
- using Axios
- using Vuejs

Thanks to everyone who is taking their time to read this!

Answer (score 1):

in request you can add custome message using
public fucntion message(){
"name.required"                 => "Name is required.",
//like this for each validation you will get different message which you can apply on page
}

Comment: The doc : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages